# Default File output using FileOutputStream?

Tags: java

I'm testing out some object serialization for my database in order to read objects from an .ser file.

When defining FileOutputStream's location, how should I do it so that it simply writes the file in the current project package?

Here is my current class:

```
public class RunSerialization {
static ProfileCollection pc;
static Profile p;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    pc = new ProfileCollection();
    p = new Profile(123,"John","Smith","123asd", Roles.ADMIN);
    pc.addProfile(p);

    try{
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("profiles.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(pc);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.printf("Data has been saved in profiles.ser");
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean with "current project package"? Do you mean folder?

Comment: That will write it to the current working directory, which if you're in an IDE might not be where you expect. I suggest you specify a "well-known" external path.

Comment: @Elliot, I'm using IntelIJ, I don't need to directly see the file itself, I just want to make sure it's always accessible by the program whenever it's created on any computer

Comment: @Booch Which is why I suggested a "well-known" path, maybe "c:/config/profiles.ser" which would always use the path `c:\config\profiles.ser` (note that backslash is an escape character, so you either use `/config` or `\\config`).

Comment: Ah alright Elliot great idea, also if you specify a file location and the folder does not exist, will it create it? Example, "c:/config/database/profiles.ser". If "database" does not exist, will it try to create a folder named "database"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone ahead and wrapped this around a method that read .ser files from your project directory.

```
/**
 * @throws IOException Input Output Exception
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException The class "file.ser" has not
 * been found in the project directory
 */
public void openCollection() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        FileInputStream e = new FileInputStream("file.ser");
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(e);
        inputStream.readObject();
}
```